# Rendering many connected quarto documents

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr, quarto

I have been trying the new [quarto](https://quarto.org/) tool by Rstudio and it seems like I cannot do something that was doable in the older versions of the *R Notebook* or *R Markdown* alternatives.

I want to organise my workflow through several quarto documents (.qmd) and I want to generate the .html documents to share with people who are not R users. For example, let's suppose I have the following 4 documents:

- 01_DataProcessing.qmd
- 02_StatisticalAnalysis.qmd
- 03_Plots.qmd
- 04_Reports.qmd

In **01_DataProcessing.qmd** I clean and organise all data to be used in the other three files. Therefore, the other three files depend on **01_DataProcessing.qmd**, *01_DataProcessing.qmd  has to be run firstly so the other files can run. Within Rstudio this works perfectly because all data in the environment is accessible to all .qmd files.

Nevertheless, when I want to generate the .hmtl files I have to *"render"* the .qmd files. Here is where I am finding problems. It seems like the rendering ignore all variables in the global environment (and all loaded libraries) and therefore it shows and error (*Execution halted*). It means that I can only work with stand-alone documents with all the code, something that might be problematic for large workflows.

Am I missing something? Do I have to change some of my settings? is there any workaround? How can I specify the .qmd to use all data available in the global environment?

Please note that with newest version of Rstudio changing to .rmd does not solve the problem since the behaviour is the same as with .qmd documents. Also, please not that in the past this was not the case.

#### Edit

To give a reproducible example, suppose in the first `qmd` file **01_DataProcessing.qmd**, I have created a data.frame `TestData` and I want to use the `TestData` in the **03_Plots.qmd** file

**01_DataProcessing.qmd**

````
---
title: "01_DataProcessing"
format: html
editor: visual
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

TestData <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
  y = c(1 ,2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
```
````

**03_Plots.qmd**

````
---
title: "03_Plots"
format: html
editor: visual
---

If you try to render the file the execution is halted because the object TestData is not found. 

```{r}
plot(TestData$x, TestData$y)
```
````

Comment: Hi, try to provide a reproducible example. For example, create only two .qmd files that are connected the way you do it, and show that if a package is loaded in the first file, it is not detected in the second file. It's harder to help you if you explain your problem without showing any examples.

Comment: Thank you,  I just added it: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/s6qzw95pc49ydu5qtlhm4/h?dl=0&rlkey=4h0d01zbnjs7929vvblyckuef

Comment: @OrlandoSabogal, I have added those shared files explicitly in the questions, since its always better to include code in the questions directly instead of sharing links, and also tried to add some descriptions relevant to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach could be saving the r objects from the first `qmd` file in a `.Rdata` file and then loading that `.Rdata` file at the very beginning of the second `qmd` document and also using an R-script file that contains the all library calls and source this r-script file at the beginning of each `qmd` file.

Now assuming that all of these related files are in the same directory (i.e folder),

---

**globals.R**

`globals.R` file contains all the necessary library calls and may contain common r objects (vectors, data.frame, etc) and common R.options that we would want to use in every `qmd` file and we will source this r-script file at the beginning of each `qmd` file.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
```

---

**01_DataProcessing.qmd**

We save the `TestData1` and `TestData2` data.frame objects in the `data_process.Rdata` file so that we can use them in the later files.

````
---
title: "01_DataProcessing"
format: html
---

```{r}
#| label: setup-globals
#| include: false

source("globals.R")
```

```{r}
TestData1 <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
  y = c(1 ,2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
  )

TestData2 <- data.frame(
  x = 6:10,
  y = 6:10
  )
```

```{r}
#| include: false

save(TestData1, TestData2, file = "data_process.Rdata")
```
````

---

**03_Plots.qmd**

In this file, we can load that `data_process.Rdata` file and `TestData1` and `TestData2` data.frame objects are available to use.

````
---
title: "03_Plots"
format: html
---

```{r}
#| label: setup
#| include: false

source("globals.R")
load("data_process.Rdata")

```

```{r}
plot(TestData1$x, TestData1$y)
plot(TestData2$x, TestData2$y)
```
````

---

Now we can render these files sequentially and everything works as intended (Hopefully!).

Now to add some more suggestions

- If we set up a Rstudio-project containing these files, we can use project specific `.Rprofile` instead of a global R file as done [in this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73536041/10858321) which saves us from sourcing that r-script file in each `qmd` files.
- If it is only the data.frame that we want to pass between sequential files, we can also write those data.frame as CSV files in a specific data directory inside the project directory and read them in later files (using the [`{here}`](https://here.r-lib.org/) package is recommended by many in such situations)

Comment: thanks for your response. This is probably the best workaround I have seen.  Just to make sure: So Quarto/Rstudio do not allow by any means (aside from your workaround solutions) the behaviour I am proposing?

Comment: AFAIK there's no default option to do this from quarto side so far. See [the comment from this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72544775/passing-data-from-one-qmd-file-to-another-in-a-quarto-book-template?rq=1) by @cderv, which points to some informative disucssions about this on Github.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at M-K rendering option from bookdown. Might be what you are looking for.
https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/new-session.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In summary: in bookdown there are two approaches to rendering a book, merge-and-knit (MK) and knit-and-merge (KM). With MK all chapters are render as one merged Rmd so it's the same global environment for everything. KM is knitting each chapter in a separate session and then merging. There each chapter is in a separate environment. Quarto only supports KM. Every chapter is rendered separately. See here: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/3577